# Packaging a .NET exe with resources

Tags: c#, .net, package

I'd like to share a application I made in C# online, but it uses a few libraries(SFML and its extlibs) along with a few images.
Is it possible for me to do something like in Java, where all the files are zipped up into a jar that can be opened directly? Or is my only choice to upload a normal zip file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no archive format like JAR for .NET.  You can merge multiple .NET assemblies into one using ILMerge and you can embed the images in the EXE as resources but, to the best of my knowledge, that's as far as it goes.  If you have unmanaged libraries then they must be distributed separately, in a regular ZIP file or the like.

Comment: Well SFML requires cSFML dll files...so that wont work right?